# How to add a method attribute?

Tags: python, methods, attributes

Is it possible to add a method attribute to a python class:

```
# something similar to this perhaps:
p.new_salary_getter = lambda(self, i) { return self.salaries[i] }
```

Here is a complete example context:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name: str, age: int) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

p = Person("oren", 28)
for i in range(12):
    if hasattr(p, "salaries"):
        salaries = getattr(p, "salaries")
        salaries[i] = 1000*i
    else:
        p.salaries = {i: 1000*i}

def getter(i: int) -> int:
    return self.salaries[i]

p.get_salary = getter
p.get_salary(7)
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    p.get_salary(7)
  File "main.py", line 15, in getter
    return self.salaries[i]
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: What happened when you tried this? Did it work? Were there any errors?

Comment: Please update your question with your actual code *and* the full error traceback.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions

Comment: You seem to know what `{` and `}` do in Pyhton, not sure why you decided to use them to define a lambda

Comment: Hi @quamrana , I edited a complete trial + posted error

Comment: @DeepSpace it was basically just to demonstrate the problem - but I edited my question

Comment: I cannot understand the logic of you are trying to achieve - why is defining `get_salary(i)` method for an object not a valid option?

Comment: @matszwecja Oh I have an answer for that - this is not *my* source code - I only use that class

Comment: To add the method to the class you have to add it to the class (not the instance): `Person.get_salary = getter`. And of course you have to provide `self`: `def getter(self, i: int) -> int:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are defining your own function now and not using a `lambda`, I'll switch to that strategy.

Here is some code which 'works' where a class has a method added later:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name: str, age: int) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

p = Person("oren", 28)

p.salaries = [1,2,3]

def getter(self, i: int) -> int:
    return self.salaries[i]

Person.get_salary = getter
print(p.get_salary(0))
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: thanks, I resorted to the getter function since I couldn't provide something reasonable in the context of the question (as far as syntax errors). Actually both formats are good for me (self-answered for future users)

Answer (score 1):

TLDR lambda style:

```
Person.get_salary = lambda self, i: self.salaries[i]
```

Future me: you were missing the `Person.` and the `lambda` without `return`